# Get object from ListView in android

Tags: android, listview

I want to get object from `ListView`. I put my data from a `csv` file.

I have two column and around 100 rows. First column is Name, second is number.
I want get number after clicking on a row.

So I have in `onCreate`:

```
listView.setClickable(true);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn2.setEnabled(true);
        Object listItem = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String item = ( listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        btn2.setText(item);

    }
});
```

And after that when I click on a row (first and second column= the same score), my `Button` text shows `[LJAVA.LANG.STRING;@42791450`, every row have other numbers.

**EDIT:**

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view2);
    itemArrayAdapter = new ItemArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.single_list_item);

    Parcelable state = listView.onSaveInstanceState();
    listView.setAdapter(itemArrayAdapter);
    listView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);

    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.manager_number);
    CSVReader csv = new CSVReader(inputStream);
    List<String[]> scoreList = csv.read();


    for (String[] scoreData : scoreList) {
        itemArrayAdapter.add(scoreData);

    }
```

Comment: You are impressing the identifier of the object and not the object's corresponding number. You need to implement an Object and it's corresponding setters and getters, and retrieve the value you wish. Ex: btn2.setText(listView.getItemAtPosition(position).getNumber());

Comment: Show the adapter initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a way to retrieve the object from your `ItemArrayAdapter`, for example `itemArrayAdapter.get(index)`, you could declare it as an instance attribute and use the position as index. Like so:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {

  private ItemArrayAdapter itemArrayAdapter;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.itemArrayAdapter = new ItemArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.single_list_item);

    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.manager_number);
    CSVReader csv = new CSVReader(inputStream);
    List<String[]> scoreList = csv.read();

    for (String[] scoreData : scoreList) {
      itemArrayAdapter.add(scoreData);
    }    

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view2);
    listView.setClickable(true);
    Parcelable state = listView.onSaveInstanceState();
    listView.setAdapter(itemArrayAdapter);
    listView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn2.setEnabled(true);
        String item = this.itemArrayAdapter.get(position);;
        btn2.setText(item);

     }
   });
```